# Позиционирование двух блоков по центру с одинаковой шириной в 50%

Tags: html, css

Как спозиционировать два одинаковых блока по центру с одинаковой шириной в 50%?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {  
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    .first, .second {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Так как `float: left` здесь неуместен, `div`'ы оказываются один под другим.

Как правильно сделать так, чтоб они находились рядом друг с другом? Фиксированная ширина меня не интересует.

Comment: А стили для `.first, .second` внутри стилей для `.wrapper` - это вообще допустимо?

Comment: Как вариант решения проблемы с шириной из-за границ можно использовать  `width: calc(50% - 4px);`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x42783o/1/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Большинство браузеров разделяет строчные блоки (элементы) отступами

http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-margins

2. добавьте `border-box: box-sizing`  - http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

`width 100%` + `border` > `width 100%`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.first,
.second {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first{
  background: #ccc;
}
.second{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">1</div>
  <div class="second">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, мешает свойство `border`, которое выдавливает ширину блоков за 50%

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий пример с **float**

```css
/* Код внутри .wrapper нужен, чтобы автоматически
   сбросить float после блоков.
   Работает в IE8 и выше.
   Если, нужны более старые браузеры,
   воспользуйтесь способом "clearfix" */

.wrapper:after {      
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper .left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrapper .right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit cum natus, temporibus sed totam nisi perferendis deserunt. Id, architecto, assumenda.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit cum natus, temporibus sed totam nisi perferendis deserunt. Id, architecto, assumenda.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

если не хочется возиться с `float` и `box-sizing` по каким-то причинам не подходит, то можно совсем просто:

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.first, .second {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

работает от IE8 и выше.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понял, почему `float` не уместен, однако ...

Вам нужно определить для классов `.first` и `.second` свойство `box-sizing` со значением `border-box` И убрать пробельные символы между элементами с указанными классами.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"></div><div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.first,
.second {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0j0ddrvj/